# Search in Embedded Documents in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have document as shown

```
[
    {
        "Users": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Kartikey Vaish",
                        "_id": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Witcher Proxima",
                        "_id": "2",
                    }
                 ],
        "_id": "12",
    },
    {
        "Users": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Witcher Proxima",
                        "_id": "2",
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Saga",
                        "_id": "4",
                    }
                 ],
        "_id": "13",
    }
]
```

I want to search for those documents whose Users array has that particular ID

For Example if

```
ID == 1 // should return

 [
    {
        "Users": [
                       {
                           "Name": "Kartikey Vaish",
                           "_id": "1",
                       },
                       {
                           "Name": "Witcher Proxima",
                           "_id": "2",
                       }
               ],
          "_id": "12",
    }
]


ID == 2 // should return

 [
    {
        "Users": [
                       {
                           "Name": "Kartikey Vaish",
                           "_id": "1",
                       },
                       {
                           "Name": "Witcher Proxima",
                           "_id": "2",
                       }
               ],
          "_id": "12",
    },
    {
        "Users": [
                       {
                           "Name": "Witcher Proxima",
                           "_id": "2",
                       },
                       {
                           "Name": "Saga",
                           "_id": "4",
                       }
               ],
          "_id": "13",
    }
]

ID == 4 // should return

 [
    {
        "Users": [
                       {
                           "Name": "Kartikey Vaish",
                           "_id": "1",
                       },
                       {
                           "Name": "Saga",
                           "_id": "4",
                       }
               ],
          "_id": "13",
    }
]
```

As you can see from above my query should return only those objects whose "Users" array contains an object with given ID. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
const chats = await Chats.find({
      Users: { $elemMatch: { _id: "1" } },
    });
// this returns an empty array

const chats = await Chats.find({
  Users: { $elemMatch: { Name: "Kartikey Vaish" } },
});
// this returns 
 [
    {
        "Users": [
                       {
                           "Name": "Kartikey Vaish",
                           "_id": "1",
                       },
                       {
                           "Name": "Witcher Proxima",
                           "_id": "2",
                       }
               ],
          "_id": "12",
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Is it something related to _id paramter?

EDIT:
My Chats Schema looks like this -

```
const Chats = mongoose.model(
  "Chats",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    Users: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      default: [],
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: Your query is correct. Check your schema once. If possible post `chats` schema.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat I have added the Chats schema in the Question

Comment: Why are u messing up with the default `ObjectId` i.e., `_id` field? If you want to capture  user id then create a new field `id`(or something) of `Number` datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your schema as shown below

```js
const Chats = mongoose.model(
  "Chats",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    Users: [{
      _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true, // Include only if needed!
        unique: true    // Include only if needed!
      },
      Name: {
        type: String,
        index: true    // Include only if needed!
      }
    }]
  })
);
```

If you do not explicitly mention `_id` MongoDB will create `_id` field as `ObjectId`.

Comment: Yes, after changing the Chats schema it worked!